# How to join DML statemens in an object command's CommandText

Tags: vb.net, oracle, ora-00911

For taking data from SQL Server database, I can use the code as below

```
Dim sql As String = "SELECT emp_id, emp_name FROM emp; SELECT dep_id, dep_name FROM department;"
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql, connString)
Dim ds As New DataSet("Data")

da.Fill(ds)
```

I will get two tables in **ds** dataset. How can I code the same for Oracle database? I try to  code as the above, but I got the error msg. **ORA-00911: Invalid character**

Moreover, I'd like to use the DELETE statement also. For e.g.

```
Dim sql As String = "DELETE FROM emp WHERE emp_id = 1; DELETE FROM department WHERE dep_id = 4"
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute multiple DML statements by a Command object, the statements must be put in a block **BEGIN ... END**. For e.g.

```
Dim sql As String = "BEGIN DELETE FROM emp WHERE emp_id = 1; DELETE FROM department WHERE dep_id = 4; End;"
...
```